# Applet works fine in netbeans IDE 8.0, not in browser

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, applet

This is simple Applet code to connect applet to database.
This code works fine when tried in Netbeans IDE 8.0. It's not showing any error.
But in browser it shows error!

this is the java applet code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class test_applet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;

@Override
public void init() {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the applet */
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    bt_clickme = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lab_disp = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    bt_clickme.setText("Click me");
    bt_clickme.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bt_clickmeActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lab_disp.setText("Click Buttton to connect to database");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                    .addComponent(bt_clickme, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                    .addComponent(lab_disp)))
            .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(51, 51, 51)
            .addComponent(lab_disp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 51, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(bt_clickme)
            .addGap(113, 113, 113))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void bt_clickmeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sas","root","");
         st=con.createStatement();

         lab_disp.setText("Database is connected successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error found when button is clicked "+e);
            }
}                                          


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton bt_clickme;
private javax.swing.JLabel lab_disp;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

and this is html file which was generated by netbeans

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>



<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="test_applet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Spent whole day in finding error!
Can anyone tell me what is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: At a guess? [Security sandbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html), which prevents you from connecting to any host except that which served you the applet.

Comment: how to overcome this problem.??

Comment: Read the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

Comment: In modern browsers you have to sign(digital signature) the applet in order to make it work